# problems configuring Hibernate with spring boot, CommandLineRunner

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring Tool Suite to create a Spring Boot application that uses Hibernate.

Here's my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:someurl
spring.datasource.username=somename
spring.datasource.password=somepassword
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

I'm trying to run the following CommandLineRunner:

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner demo(CustomerRepository repository) {
    return (args) -> {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

        ServiceRegistryBuilder registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
        registry.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = registry.buildServiceRegistry();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

        Customer e1 = new Customer();
        //blah blah blah
        session.persist(e1);

        t.commit();

        session.close();


    };
}
```

My problem is:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
```

looks for "hibernate.cfg.xml" and all my hibernate config is in application.properties

How do I cause the Hibernate config stuff to initialize itself with the stuff in application.properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configurations are automatically loaded with application properties if you are using spring boot.It would be needed only if additional configurations are required or if modifying an existing configuration programatically.

I guess,you do not need either of them for this job,that is ,you could always use this and not set configuration to get sessionfactory :

```
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class) == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Not a hibernate factory exception");
    }
    return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
}
```

This way , your configurations are loaded automatically and you get your sessionfactory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, if my hibernate/jpa configs are in applications.properties, are you saying I can access them thru an autowired EntityManagerFactory?

Comment: Yes,or for that matter just Entity manager,for example :      @PersistenceContext(unitName = "default")
 private EntityManager entityManager; entityManager.find(args..)

Comment: Also,remember,if you are using spring boot and hibernate JPA,entities(aka Customer) in your case should be in the same maven module ,basically in entityscan(@EntityScan(basePackages = ....)) and Customer should be annotated with @Entity..

Comment: So how exactly do you use the entityManagerFactory to create a session?